# building target package from assets archive and pre-built binaries unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I want to publish my android game which I create in unity but in the process of build, I got this error ((building target package from assets archive and pre-built binaries)). Console shows:

> (( CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to build apk. C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M
>
> ### -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:/Android SDK\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "D:\Unity\Nasb\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar"
>
> stderr[ Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at
>   SDKMain.main(SDKMain.java:129) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/BASE64Encoder    at
>   com.android.sdklib.internal.build.SignedJarBuilder.(SignedJarBuilder.java:177)
>     at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.init(ApkBuilder.java:446)    at
>   com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.(ApkBuilder.java:422)   at
>   com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.(ApkBuilder.java:362)   at
>   UnityApkBuilder.(UnityApkBuilder.java:214)  at
>   UnityApkBuilder.main(UnityApkBuilder.java:34)     ... 5 more Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.misc.BASE64Encoder  at
>   java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
>     ... 11 more ] stdout[
>
> ] exit code: 1 UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run
>   (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi,
>   UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit,
>   System.String errorMsg)
>   UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandInternal (System.String
>   javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand,
>   Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir,
>   UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit,
>   System.String errorMsg)
>   UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandSafe (System.String
>   javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand,
>   Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir,
>   UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit,
>   System.String errorMsg) UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI() ))

What should I do??

Answer (score 0):

After fighting some hours, I finally find the answer. The problem was caused by my JDK version. I used JDK version 11 and the problem appeared. Then, I installed JDK 8 and the problem fixed.